# How to ignore characters with Python Regex

Tags: python, regex

I am wondering if there is a better Python Regex solution for the one that I currently have?  Currently my code is:

```
import re

n = '+17021234567'
m = '7021234567'
match = re.search(r'(?:\+1)?(\d{10})', n)
match.group(1)

match = re.search(r'(?:\+1)?(\d{10})', m)
match.group(1)
```

The goal of the code is to only extract the 10 digit ph # if it has a leading `+1` or not.  Currently it works, but I am wondering is there a way to just call `match.group()` to get the 10 digit ph # without calling `match.group(1)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, without the use of capturing groups, it couldn't be possible through `re.match` function. Since re.match tries to match the input string from the beginning. But it could be possible through `re.search`

```
>>> re.search(r'\d{10}$', n).group()
'7021234567'
>>> re.search(r'\d{10}$', m).group()
'7021234567'
```

Comment: I don't think OP meant re.match but the variable match the they used

Answer (score 1):

you want to only capture digit use '\d' for digit

```
n = '+17021234567'
re.findall('\d{10}$',n)
```

Answer (score 1):

use this pattern

```
(?<=^|\+1)\d{10}$
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/69)

> ```
> (?<=                    look behind to see if there is:
>   ^                       the beginning of the string
>  |                        OR
>   \+1                     '+1'
> )                        end of look-behind
> \d{10}                   digits (0-9) (10 times)
> $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the string
> ```